# Lubuntu App Icon Bug in Tray

Tags: lubuntu, icons, themes, lxqt

I'm using Lubuntu 19.10 currently, and most of the apps I'm running in my tray are shown with a generic icon instead of their original icon. E.g. `discord`, `touchpad-indicator`, `telegram-desktop`. You can see a sample here: (See the mouse cursor)

[image]

This becomes really annoying when I have multiple apps in the background. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Do you get the same result with other icon themes?

Comment: @DKBose By changing the theme it works temporarily but after a reboot it happens again. Also when I start `discord`(which is installed using snap), the tray icon is right but when I change the focus of the window the tray icon becomes generic again.